# BrowserHistory never gets initialized in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm very new to ReactJS. I was trying some tutorials to do routing but end up with errors where the "browserHistory" was undefined. The code and error message is as below.

**Main.js**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory,browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import App from './App.jsx';
import {Home,About,Contact} from './App.jsx';


ReactDOM.render((
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "about" component = {About} />
         <Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
      </Route>
   </Router>

), document.getElementById('app'))
```

**Error Message from browser console**

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in
>   `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.in Router

Kindly let me know if the implementation is out-of-date or if I have missed out any libraries to face this problem

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the reason, the new react-router does not support browserHistory anymore. To achieve the same goal I have used the following code.

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `useRouterHistory`:

```
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

const createAppHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory);

const history = createAppHistory({
 parseQueryString: parse,
 stringifyQuery: stringify
})

<Router history={history}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

React Router v4 changed things. They made separate top level router elements. Replace `<Router history={hashHistory}>` with `<HashRouter>` in your code.

```
import {HashRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

<HashRouter>
    <Route path = "/" component = {App} />
</HashRouter>
```